# Prove a set of functions is a sub space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

Let $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R} $ be a vector-space of functions $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$.

The set of functions $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ so that $f(-1) + f(1) = 0$ are an example of subspace?

I know I have to prove 0 is in the set, the sum of two vectors (functions) is in the set and the scalar product is in the set.
I have 9 different groups to check whether they are sub spaces or not, but really don't know the method to proceed with the question, so I would like this as an example.

Thanks!

Comment: If you add two functions who both satisfy your property, check they they too satisfy the property.  If you multiply a function which satisfies your property by a real number, check that the result too satisfies the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is. We define $S$ as following $$S=\{f|f(1)+f(-1)=0\}$$simply $0\in S$. Now if $f$ and $g$ are in $S$ we have $$f(1)+f(-1)=0\\g(1)+g(-1)=0$$therefore$$(af+bg)(1)+(af+bg)(-1)=a(f(1)+f(-1))+b(g(1)+g(-1))=0$$for any $a,b\in\Bbb R$ therefore $S$ is a subspace

Comment: I see, this clarified it for me.

Then by the following logic, if we have the group f(0) + f(1) = 1, it is not a subspace because:

(f+g)(0) + (f+g)(1) = (f(0) + f(1)) + (g(0) + g(1)) = 2

correct?

Comment: That's right. Furthermore $0\notin S$ which is another argument ....

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=0$ for all $x$ implies $f\in S :=\{f|f(1)+f(-1)=0\} $ and if $g,h\in S$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$  then $ag(1)+bh(1)+ag(-1)+bh(-1)=a(g(1)+g(-1))+b(h(1)+h(-1))=0$. So, $ag+bh\in S$. So, $S$ is a sub-space.